# Connecting to ibm MQ via liberty server config failed due to SSL handshake issue

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, java-8, ibm-mq, open-liberty

I have configured server.xml from this reference link (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/nd?topic=dmal-deploying-jms-applications-liberty-use-mq-messaging-provider) .Initially we made the channel NON-SSL and the above config is working and we are able to get the response from the queue.

However when the channel is SSL we are getting "Unable to find valid certification to the requested target"

we have default ssl tag in the xml
<ssl id="defaultSSLConfig" keyStoreRef= trustStoreRef=/>

Somehow it is not picking up these default ssl config during dynamic outbound connection ...

This is a burning issue for us..can anyone help me out please

Comment: So where are your certificates stored?

Comment: In WAS server we have a folder to store those certs

Comment: Can you confirm in the error message you quoted in your problem description the word "path" is missing and the error is "Unable to find valid certification path to the requested target"? In this case I'd double check the CA certificate which was used to sign the MQ certificate had been added to your specified trust store as a trusted root.

Comment: Let me confirm it once and i will revert and meanwhile can u share amy server.xml file that connects to ibm mq (openlibrrty) that would help

Comment: Basically what you need  to add to your current jmsConnectionFactory definition in server.xml is the parameter sslCipherSuite. "Any server.xml" is here on page 7: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/system/files/support/swg/swgdocs.nsf/0/e966dfd8c51c6b6f85257f1e006dfb4a/$FILE/WMQ_Liberty_SSL_Setup.pdf

Comment: I have tried that as well but no change in the error

Comment: The error is not about a wrong cipher, it is about the missing certification path. I have just added the reference to the connection factory setting, because you have asked for it.